# Singular cohomology of complex projective space

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

In the article "What is ... Equivariant Cohomology?" by Loring W. Tu (https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.4293), I read that

$H^*(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty},\mathbb{R})\simeq \mathbb{R}[u]$,

where $H^*()$ denotes the singular cohomology (functor), $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}=\cup_n \mathbb{C}P^{n}$ and $\mathbb{R}[u]$ is the polynomial ring generated by an element $u$ of degree 2.

I don't see this equivalence. Can you explain me why it is so?

Comment: Read any standard textbook on algebraic topology.

Comment: Following @CaveJohnson comment, in case the OP doesn't know where to look it up, *Algebraic Topology* by Allen Hatcher, Theorem 3.19.

Comment: Thanks, @Javi. At a first look, the theorem you suggested seams to concern $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty},\mathbb{Z})$ rather than $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty},\mathbb{R})$. Hopefully, I will figure it out on my own...

Comment: @M.Marciani for $\Bbb{R}$ is analogous and probably there are shortcuts since $\Bbb{R}$ is a field and that always makes things easier.